# LexOffice API format issue

Tags: c#, rest

//This code snippet should create a delivery note and send it to the api

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string apiUrl = "https://api.lexoffice.io/v1/delivery-notes";
    string apiToken = "Dummy_Token"; 

    string jsonData = @"
    {
        ""recipient"": {
            ""name"": ""Max Mustermann"",
            ""address"": ""Musterstraße 123"",
            ""zip"": ""12345"",
            ""city"": ""Musterstadt"",
            ""country"": ""DE""
        },
        ""items"": [
            {
                ""name"": ""Produkt 1"",
                ""quantity"": 2,
                ""unitPrice"": 10.5,
                ""taxRate"": 19
            },
            {
                ""name"": ""Produkt 2"",
                ""quantity"": 1,
                ""unitPrice"": 15.0,
                ""taxRate"": 19
            }
        ]
    }";
```

//This is the format I have tried but I always get the bad request Error.//
The format is wrong and I dont know whats the correct format for the https-request

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.